# Tableau extracts update

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to know if there's a way to automatically update my extracts?

I have a live connection with redshift and use tableau desktop and publish some workbooks on tableau online.

I like to share some reports using extracts and tableau reader and I really need a way to update the extracts everyday

Answer (score 2):

if I understand your question correctly, you should be able to refresh your Tableau Data Extracts by setting up "Refresh Schedules" on Tableau Online. Tableau Online supports variety of [Data Sources](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_keep_data_fresh.htm) to set up Extracts instead of using Live Connection.
Check this [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/schedule_add.htm) on setting up refresh schedules.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do set refresh schedule that will help you to update your extract automatically without any manual effort but there are some terms & conditions you have to follow:

1. For this you have to set your dashboards/workbooks/project in "Extract" mode & not in LIVE.
2. I personally recommend "extracts" instead of LIVE until the person who is looking for this need REAL TIME updates
3. Also, you need to set this schedule from Admin's ID (Publisher access) which you use to publish your work from Desktop to Online
4. Note: You only can choose from lot of options already available 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5NjS.jpg)